# chart js star legend edit pointstyle sides

Tags: javascript, chart.js

im using chart js and using legend pointstyle star, but the star is 8 sides or * like this. is there a way to set the sides to normal star shape

here's my script

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/chart.js"></script>
    <script>
        const ctx = document.getElementById('myChart');
        
        new Chart(ctx, {
            type: 'line',
            data: {
                labels: ['Red', 'Blue', 'Yellow', 'Green', 'Purple', 'Orange'],
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'star',
                    data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    pointStyle: 'star',
                }]
            },
            options: {
                scales: {
                    y: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
```

i tried searching the net and on their docs, i couldn't find any solution.